# How to use DateAdd in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to convert VB to c#, in VB **DATEADD** Working in C# it gives an Error

```
DateTime viewPortStartDate = DateAdd("s", viewer.ViewPortLeft * m_dateRange, m_dtmMinDate);
DateTime  viewPortEndDate = DateAdd("s", viewer.ViewPortWidth * m_dateRange, viewPortStartDate);
```

Comment: It gives you an error? Then please show it to us. You've just given us code and says "It doesn't work". In what way doesn't it work?

Answer (score 5):

Its AddDays in C#:

```
viewPortStartDate.AddDays(1);
```

If you want a range, you can use duration:

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0); //Adding 7 days from date today
 DateTime result = today.Add(duration);
```

For adding with Hours, Minutes and seconds, you can do:

```
 today = today.AddDays(1).AddHours(1).AddMinutes(1).AddSeconds(1);
```

Or if specific to seconds only:

```
today = today.AddSeconds(1);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I need using seconds. like the same.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by using seconds but I updated my code for you to check if that's what you need. @Suresh